# Using Logic Apps with HTTP header hosted under Azure API Management

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

We have API exposed to our customers through API Management. The security is handled using subscription key which is expected in "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key" header.

One of our methods supports polling trigger specifications, with "Location" and "Retry-After" header in response. For one of our customers we want to create Logic Apps, that would fire some actions on this trigger.

We set up HTTP trigger where we provided "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key" header in inputs parameters.

Here is the problem. The header is added only to the first request. Subsequent requests using "Location" url don't have this "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key" header, so they are rejected by API Management proxy.

I verified that header is in fact missing with some mock API, so it's definitely on Logic Apps end.

Does anyone have any idea how to resolve it?

Comment: This is a current limitation of the logic apps runtime, but I agree that if the location headers points back at the same APIM instance the header should be included. We will consider fixing this.

Comment: @SzymonWylezol, The ApiConnector type of trigger, I'm little bit confused with documentation about that one. Can it replace HTTP header, or it's something completely different?

Comment: @SzymonWylezol Also, I read somewhere that key can be passed through URL as query parameter, which we can add to Location header using outbound policies, but when I tried it, it didn't work. Does this option exist?

Comment: you can specify headers for any http-based action/trigger type (including ApiConnection and ApiManagement), and these should be attached to both the original request and any continuation specified via location header.

Comment: to clarify the above: headers do get attached to original requests in all cases. only for basic Http actions whey are attached to continuation requests as well (ApiConnection and ApiManagement operations would not include the original headers when following continuations).

Comment: if you include the ocp-apim-subscription-key as a query parameter in the location header, then it should be included when the logic app engine follows the location (it is treated as an opaque uri). when you say "it didn't work" do you mean it wasn't providedin the uri, or your requests wouldn't authenticate with APIM?

Comment: Now I'm confused. We do use HTTP trigger, but we observe that headers are NOT attached to continuation request based on our observation. And I took your first comment as confirmation of this.

ApiConnect - I just couldn't make work at all, and the documentation is somewhat confusing. I would appreciate the clarification in that regard.

Also, couldn't make it work with ocp-apim-subscription-key  as query even in original request. Is it just ?ocp-apim-subscription-key =<key> ? Or, what is the format?

Comment: I believe in query it would be subscription-key, or just key (both should be supported). You are right wrt headers, looked at it again and it is only http action that attach headers to continuations. I agree that this is not consistent and the documentation is poor. Thanks for bringing it up.

Comment: Yes, I found somewhere, adding subscription-key to the URL in Location header value did the trick. The only problem is conceptually it's a hack to make Logic Apps work, while we consider our API to be generic. But it's workaround. Do you know if fixing headers for continuations for triggers in on a roadmap for any foreseeable future?